# Eclipse HTML Validation Setup

Tags: php, eclipse, wordpress, validation

I am trying to setup Eclipse HTML Validation for WordPress and I have read and seen several articles on here and others online that have you set a bunch of settings or just plain ignore or exclude all the WordPress folders. The reason I don't want to exclude all the folders and code is because I still want the autocomplete and other DTD functionality to work.

I noticed a option in the HTML Syntax settings, "Ignore specified element names in validation" and "Ignore specified attribute names in validation".

To start I was trying to get rid of the error:

```
Start tag (<video>) not closed properly, expected '>'
```

So I got into the settings by right clicking on my Project in the PHP Explorer and select Properties. Check the "Enable project specific settings" and enabled "Ignore specified element names in validation". Then in the Text Box I entered "video".

When I hit "OK" I get the dialog that validation settings have been changed and do I want to validate the project and I select "Yes". But nothing seems to change. Am I doing something wrong here? Am I misreading how this "should" work? Or is there a better way about going about this?

Here is a screenshot of my settings:

[image]

Comment: Is the file where the Problem is being reported actually an HTML file?

Comment: It is a PHP file. I was using this as an example. I was only wondering how to get the Ignore specific element names to work.